# NCryptImportKey fails for ECCPUBLICBLOB with NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER return code

Tags: c++, windows

Here's the code I'm using:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <windows.h>
#include <ncrypt.h>

int main()
{
    NCRYPT_PROV_HANDLE hProvider = NULL;
    if (NCryptOpenStorageProvider(&hProvider, MS_SMART_CARD_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Unable to open storage provider!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
    BYTE rawData[73] = {
        0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x31, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0xB2, 0xF2, 0x24,
        0xA4, 0xFA, 0x8E, 0x91, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x2A, 0x77, 0x3E, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0x69,
        0xAA, 0x31, 0x80, 0x12, 0xE8, 0xCE, 0x13, 0xF5, 0x19, 0x13, 0xC9, 0xF4,
        0x53, 0x67, 0x2F, 0xBC, 0x03, 0xF8, 0xE2, 0x3A, 0xB4, 0x93, 0xFE, 0x87,
        0xAA, 0xA0, 0x5B, 0xF3, 0x87, 0xC2, 0x5E, 0xB5, 0x96, 0xBA, 0xB2, 0xA6,
        0x5F, 0x5A, 0x4B, 0x5E, 0xB6, 0xD5, 0x34, 0xB1, 0x9D, 0x1D, 0x5E, 0x7A,
        0xED};

    SECURITY_STATUS status = NCryptImportKey(hProvider, NULL, L"ECCPUBLICBLOB", NULL, &hKey, rawData, sizeof(rawData), 0);
    switch (status)
    {
    case ERROR_SUCCESS:
        printf("Success.\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    case NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER:
        printf("One or more parameters are not valid.\n");
    default:
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

As we can see, I'm trying to import what I believe is an Elliptic Curve Public Key, whose hex dump is:

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  45 43 53 31 00 01 00 00 04 B2 F2 24 A4 FA 8E 91  ECS1.....²ò$¤úŽ‘
00000010  08 0F 2A 77 3E E3 E4 69 AA 31 80 12 E8 CE 13 F5  ..*w>ãäiª1€.èÎ.õ
00000020  19 13 C9 F4 53 67 2F BC 03 F8 E2 3A B4 93 FE 87  ..ÉôSg/¼.øâ:´“þ‡
00000030  AA A0 5B F3 87 C2 5E B5 96 BA B2 A6 5F 5A 4B 5E  ª [ó‡Â^µ–º²¦_ZK^
00000040  B6 D5 34 B1 9D 1D 5E 7A ED                       ¶Õ4±..^zí
```

I expected `NCryptImportKey` to return `ERROR_SUCCESS`, rather than `NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER` under this scenario.

Why is `NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER` being returned here? MSDN states that it means "One or more parameters are not valid", but which one(s)?

Comment: *"As we can see,"* -- Maybe as you can see. Not me, though. I skip over code blocks to find the text to tell me what I should be looking for in the code. This plays into the motivation for [ask] advising that questions be introduced (in the question body) **before** posting any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual size of your key does not match the size specified in the blob's header.

`"ECCPUBLICBLOB"` corresponds to the [`BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_ecckey_blob) structure.

As documented, in that structure, the first four bytes are `ULONG dwMagic`, which in your case is [`BCRYPT_ECDSA_PUBLIC_P256_MAGIC`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/shared/bcrypt.h#L432) (`0x31534345` in little-endian hex or "`ECS1`" in ASCII).

After that, the four bytes representing `ULONG cbKey` follow. This is supposed to be the length, in bytes, of the key. In your raw data, those four bytes are `0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00`, which is `0x00000100` in little-endian hex, which means 256.

The key itself is supposed to be immediately following this 8-byte header (`dwMagic` and `cbKey`) in the `BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB`. But in your code, the whole raw data is only 73 bytes long (8 bytes for the header and 65 bytes for the key itself). Where is the rest of the key?

Perhaps this is a bits vs bytes confusion, and you intended to specify 65 as the length of the key, not 256. But in that case you probably need to specify `cbKey` as 32, and the raw key data that follows needs to be 32 bytes of `X`, followed by 32 bytes of `Y` (so it is a compressed, 64-byte, key format).  See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_ecckey_blob#remarks) section for the expected structure of the buffer. The leading byte `0x04` of the key needs to be removed in the compressed format.

To sum it up, try this:

```
BYTE rawData[72] = {
        0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x31, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB2, 0xF2, 0x24, 0xA4,
        0xFA, 0x8E, 0x91, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x2A, 0x77, 0x3E, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0x69, 0xAA,
        0x31, 0x80, 0x12, 0xE8, 0xCE, 0x13, 0xF5, 0x19, 0x13, 0xC9, 0xF4, 0x53,
        0x67, 0x2F, 0xBC, 0x03, 0xF8, 0xE2, 0x3A, 0xB4, 0x93, 0xFE, 0x87, 0xAA,
        0xA0, 0x5B, 0xF3, 0x87, 0xC2, 0x5E, 0xB5, 0x96, 0xBA, 0xB2, 0xA6, 0x5F,
        0x5A, 0x4B, 0x5E, 0xB6, 0xD5, 0x34, 0xB1, 0x9D, 0x1D, 0x5E, 0x7A, 0xED };
```

Comment: Right on the mark! The length is indeed 32 (0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 little-endian)! Many thanks!